# I think, I suppose, I guess, and I reckon: is there any difference?

Tags: phrase-usage

What are the differences between 'I think', 'I suppose', 'I guess', and 'I reckon'? In which case is one more preferred than the others?

Comment: "I guess" often has complex subtexts attached to it - see my answer here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/257066/120432

Answer (score 11):

Much depends on context. The most important thing to remember is that by and large where the same general sense is intended, *guess* and *reckon* are very much more informal (suitable for casual spoken contexts, but not really for anything remotely formal). But there can also be other nuances...

---

> *"The boss said they're going to be downsizing this office. Does that mean we might be sacked?"*
>    a: *"I think so"*
>    b: *"I suppose so"*

In a context like that, *think* may simply be a "neutral" verb indicating that's what the speaker believes to be the case. But *suppose* can often convey a certain "resigned acceptance" of something which is implicitly *assumed* to be true.

That same "resigned acceptance" sense can also apply with informal *guess*. So, for example,...

> *"Let's not just have another delivery pizza tonight. How about we go out for a chinese?"*
>    a: **"I think [so]*  (NOTE - not a credible response!)
>    b: *"I suppose [so]"*
>    c: *"I guess [so]"*
>    d: *"I reckon [so]"*

In that context, (b) and (c) convey limited enthusiasm for the idea, where (d) is usually more "positive".

---

I'm sure not everyone will agree, but I personally find that of the "informal" versions, *reckon* is somewhat more dialectal/rustic/folksy than *guess*.

---

In recognition of @Tyler's now-deleted answer, note that there are contexts where the choice of verb may reflect *degree of certainty*. For example, as a response to *"I wonder why geese migrate"*...

> a: *"I think they fly south to be warm"*
>    b: *"I guess they fly south to be warm"*

Remember that just because *think/suppose* are more appropriate in formal contexts doesn't imply they're *less* appropriate in informal contexts. In the above (informal) context, *think* implies the speaker already had this opinion (possibly with near certainty), so the statement carries more conviction. On the other hand, *guess* carries more the implication *I don't know, but if I had to guess, this is what I might think* (i.e. - the "reluctance" referred to earlier applies to *willingness to express an opinion at all* here).

Comment: Excellent answer, and my intuition agrees wholeheartedly!

Comment: In terms of certainty, does 'reckon' connote more certain than 'guess'?

Comment: @dan: Not really. But in *most* contexts, ***reckon*** certainly connotes a more ***relaxed / dialectal*** register. It's certainly not the kind of word you'd be expected to use in reference to what you ***think*** in a formal / academic context.