# "I guess (so).", "I guess (that) ..." and "... , I guess."

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, usage, sentence-usage

When NAm.En native speakers say or reply with "I guess (so)",  "i guess (that) ..." and "... , I guess.",  what are the common different ways in which they use the word "guess" here as a verb in the aforementioned contexts?

I mean, can you help me with fully mastering how to use it informally in these different contexts? I didn't really find any of the good online English dictionaries out there to be that much of help or that useful with using it in its informal contexts and the other good online English dictionaries probably wouldn't be either.

So perhaps you could provide any tips you think that might better help with that.

Answer (score 2):

The verb 'to guess' means to provide an answer without knowing whether it's the right answer.

Usually, when we use the word in the way you're describing, it's because we're not sure about what we're saying but we believe that what we're correct.

> Where's George? I guess he went home, because he said he was tired, but I don't know because I didn't see him leave.

It's also used when the speaker doesn't want to commit fully to their answer for some reason. They might know what the answer is but they won't admit that they know.

> John, you hurt Sarah's feelings. Did you know that? Yeah, I guess so.

Another use is a to soften the tone of a strong suggestion that is not likely to be received enthusiastically.

> Well, if you hurt her feelings, I guess you'll have to go and apologize.

Answer (score 2):

## Common misuse

In American English, the phrase "I guess" frequently does not have the same literal meaning as the verb "to guess", and so is often misused by nonnative English speakers.

One example of this misuse can be found in this [question about predicting sports outcomes](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/216630/i-guess-theyre-going-to-lose-this-one). The OP wants to express that, though they are uncertain, they believe their team will win the game. In American English, we would generally use "I think", or even "I bet they will win the game," indicating that the speaker feels this outcome is likely, without adding any additional subtext. (Note: "Bet" is  used nonliterally, here, and does not imply making an actual wager.)

As discussed below, the phrase "I guess" often implies a subtext of doubt, disagreement, or dissatisfaction, transforming or even reversing the meaning of the sentence. Saying "I guess they will win the game," generally *does not mean that you are uncertain about what will occur, but think they might win*. Rather, the sentence is focused on its subtext. Depending on the speaker's tone of voice and the context, it might indicate that either:

- speaker is surprised that they will win
- speaker disappointed that they will win

Avoid this common misuse by preferring "I (think/believe/bet/suspect/am almost certain) they will win", and avoiding "I guess" unless you want to use one of its useful subtexts.

## Clarifying Common Usage

The verb "to guess" means "to give an answer to a particular question when you do not have all the facts and so cannot be certain if you are correct" ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/guess)) or loosely "to select the correct answer despite uncertainty".

The phrase "I guess", on the other hand, *is not generally used in American English to describe the process of guessing.* Rather, the phrase "I guess" implies some kind of internal discovery, conflict, or disagreement. This is a challenging idea to grasp, so we'll proceed by example.

**Usage 1 - Disagreement:**

Context: Laura has never been friendly to John, so John thinks she is mean. John's friend Kate meets Laura for the first time, and has a good first impression of Laura:

> Kate: "Laura is so cool!"
> John: "Sure, I guess."

Note that John is *not literally guessing anything*. If spoken aloud, "I guess" *might* be inflected similarly to the way in which Americans inflect questions, or doubt, with the word guess rising slightly in pitch, or rising and falling again rapidly. In this conversation, John is using "I guess" to politely express doubt or disagreement with Kate's opinion.

If he replied "No, Laura's really mean," that might be perceived as confrontational. Instead, he uses "I guess" to introduce uncertainty into his  agreement, producing the effect of a "softened" disagreement. Hearing John's answer, Laura might reply "You don't think so? What did she do to you?"

**Usage 2 - Doubt:**

Context: Laura has still never been friendly to John, so John thinks she is mean. John's friend Kate tells him that Laura has been helping her with her homework a lot lately.

> Kate: "John, you and Laura have a lot in common."
> John: "I guess that could be true, but she's always talking about dumb stuff."

Though John is "giving an answer without having all the facts" here, the subtext of his response is critical. By using "I guess", he *is not* saying that he suspects Kate might be right. To the contrary, he is using "I guess" to imply that he doubts Katie's statement is true. The second phrase in this example clarifies his intention. In the right context, it would be correct for John to say simply "I guess," indicating his doubt that he and Laura have anything in common with his tone of voice.

**Usage 3 - Reluctance/Resistance**

Context: immediately following the statements in Usage 2.

> Kate: "Well, you should at least try to get to know Laura better before you judge her."
> John: "I guess so, she just really bugs me."

Here, John is expressing that Katie might be right, while expressing resistance to the idea of getting to know Laura better. As in Usage 2, the second phrase in this example clarifies John's intention. In the right spoken context it would be correct for John to say simply "I guess." With a negative tone of voice, this shorter construction could indicate reluctance/resistance to Kate's suggestion. With a positive tone, it could indicate wholehearted agreement, with a subtext of... discovery!

**Usage 4 - discovery:**

Context: Laura has never been nice to John, so John thinks she is mean. One day, Kate convinces John and Laura to go for a hike with her. Once they both get over their shyness, they have a really great time. After Laura goes home, John might tell Kate

> "Wow! I guess Laura really is a nice person after all!

Note that again, John *is not guessing*. Rather, John has realized, based on new knowledge, that his prior assessment of Laura may have been incorrect. By using "I guess", John is acknowledging a change in his perspective.

A similar usage is discussed in this [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/168025/meaning-of-i-guess-i-could-just-get-the-mail-at-night), in which "I guess" is used to indicate a conflict between a currently-held expectation, and a possible schedule change. In this type of usage, "I guess" is used to indicate a significant change - of perspective, of plans, etc.

## Some literal exceptions

**From another answer**
@dwilli's first example shows one case in which "I guess" behaves similarly to "to guess". (Both other great examples in that answer showcase nonliteral uses of "guess").

Though this example is valid Am.English, it may be a little misleading. If I were the speaker, I would probably say this a little differently, for clarity. Because "I guess" is so frequently used to express doubt or conflict, my intention would impact my use.

To intentionally express doubt, confusion, or strong uncertainty that he actually went home, I would use:

> Where's George? I guess he went home? He said he was tired, but I don't know because I didn't see him leave.

Or to express my belief that George *probably did go home*, I would use:

> Where's George? I (think/bet/suspect/would guess) he went home, because he said he was tired, but I don't know because I didn't see him leave.

Note that in this construction, I use "would guess", not I guess. "Would guess" functions literally, without the subtextual baggage of "I guess."

**Literally guessing**

Note: Although the following conversation is correct Am.English, it is a relatively uncommon usage, and tone of voice is important.

> Q: "Guess a number between 1 and 10."
>
> A: "I guess 4."

In real life, the words "I guess" would often be omitted. This is more common:

> Q: "Guess a number between 1 and 10."
>
> A: "4"

Why? Probably mostly for reasons of simplicity/laziness in spoken language, but this simpler construction also avoids the different and slightly context-inappropriate subtexts of the common phrase "I guess".

Comment: There are also two Canadian uses, which often appears in the USA. First is, expressing a statement in a softened manner so as to deliberately avoid being confrontational. "Do you want some help getting your groceries inside?" "I guess so." Meaning, if it's OK. Second, exactly the reverse, an ironic answer used to be deliberately confrontational, especially when delayed for no good reason. At a restaurant when the server has been delayed talking to her friends at another table.  "Sorry I made you wait. Do you want your change now?" "I guess so!"