# I guess they're going to lose this one

Tags: word-usage

If my friend text me to ask if a particular team is going to win and I want to say: "I guess they're going to lose". And if I mean a particular match,  can I use:

> I guess they're going to lose **this one**.

Specifically, is it okay to use "this one" in that sentence?

Comment: Do you mean is *this one* fine as opposed to *this game*? In this case, *one* is a generic word that can stand in place of any number of specific nouns.

Comment: I think "think" is better than "guess". e.g. I think they are going to lose this one.

Comment: Tell me why you think you can't use it? This one//that one//these ones, those ones.

Answer (score 1):

The use of "this one" here is correct and idiomatic in American English, indicating that the team will lose this game. If emphasis is placed on the phrase "this one", the speaker may also be implying that "this one" is an exception, and that the team will "win the next one", or has won most of their previous games.

As @Ron Jensen notes, I guess is probably *not* correctly used here. See my long-form answer [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/257066/120432) for details.

Comment: It may not be correct, but it is certainly colloquial. "I'm a man, but I can change, if I have to, I guess."

Comment: I'd like to respectfully disagree, @puppetsock. Absent context, OP appears to be making a literal guess about his team's chances of success. In your construction, you are not making a literal guess about whether or not it is possible for you to change. Rather, you are using "I guess" to indicate resistance to something you assume to be possible. There is no literal guessing happening here; your "I guess" is about injecting subtext.

Comment: Well Chris, I guess you're right.